# Combination and Permutation- examples

Tags: permutations, combinations

I am not sure how to answer this question.

I have a word TOKYO.

a) how many different can I arrange the letters in a row?

b) in how many of these will O's be together?

c) how many will the two O's not together?

My thoughts:

a) I figure out that this is a permutation because order is important hence. I guess "different" also means "unique"?. Also am assuming the question says we should use all the 5 letters.

unique words $= \dfrac{5!}{2!\times1!\times1!\times1!} = 60  $

b)for this question, I got thoroughly confused. When I did the words manually, I managed to get 24 words (e.g. OOTKY OOTYK  OOKTY .....YTKOO YKTOO.)
But I cant seem to figure out the formula for this. I thought it is also a permutation:

$5P2 which would be \dfrac{5!}{(5-2)!} = \dfrac{5!}{3!} = 20 $

c) for this question, I subtract answers in  $ a-b =60-20 = 30 $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a) Correct!

b) Treat the 2 Os as one group, so there are 4 groups in total, hence 4!

c) a)-b)